# Gitlab pipeline not saving build files

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm very new to gitlab pipelines and done some research on them but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm currently trying to build a maven project through a shell git runner on my VPS and after that have the code available on my vps so I can start the jar whenever I want to.

Problem is whenever my pipeline gets called the logs are OK and the maven project gets build like it should. But after it has been build and the artifact has been saved to gitlab it doesn't save any files to my vps, at least I cannot find them. From what I've read every build should be saved in the `/home/gitlab-runner` folder but after a build is successful there is nothing to see there.

This is the script I am currently running :

```
image: maven:3-jdk-11

stages:
- test
- build
sast:
  stage: test
include:
- template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

deploying-to-remote-host:
  stage: build
  only:
    - production
  script:
    - mvn -v
    - mvn -f Server -e clean package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - Server/target/*.jar
```

Does anyone know if I have to add more code to it for it to save the builds to my `home/gitlab-runner` directory?

Comment: Is it normal your gitlab-ci in example doesn't contain job in build stage ?